# How to open a view within a view in .Net Core MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I am developing a .Net Core application using MVC in Visual Studio 2017.

I have been developing on it for some time, and 7 months ago I took a break. Now I have returned to develop further on it. Back then I "learned" that the way to render a view within a view was to create a `partialView` and render that using javascript/jQuery as follows:

```
$("#div_name").load(<some-url>, { id: <some-id> }, function() {
    console.log("loaded successfully");
)};
```

I assume there are different "integrated" methods for doing this? I find it hard to believe that the only way to load a view within a view is by using javascript/jQuery. Does anyone have some knowledge to share? I can't seem to find anything on Google (but that might just be because I don't know what to search for).

I have been reading up on partialViews and have found that these "can" be loaded from Razor, but if I want to get data from my database context I am unsure of how this would go about. Furthermore found something called components which I will take a look into myself.

However my current problem is that I have a table in my view:
[image]

I want it to be that whenever I click a row inside that table I download some data from my DbContext (using my controller) and that data should be put inside a new view that is loaded within the first view so it would be like follows:
[image]

Right now it works when I use static "test" data that I generate myself, inside my controller, but not when I try to connect to my DbContext in my controller, even though I am using async calls, I get no data passed through the view.

I would think that .Net Core might have some other way to do this, as I think it is quite tedious to use javascript/jQuery to do this. Am I completely wrong?

## EDIT:

After I did some error checking in my code I managed to get it to work (I had my input value to my Controller method receive an `int` when in fact the value passed was 15 characters long and started with a 3 (larger than the largest value allowed for an `int`). As soon as I changed the input to the method to a `long` it worked and I got my desired output. However I would still like to know if there's a different way to do this in .Net Core MVC.

Comment: If i were doing what you are describing, I would use a jQuery onclick method to fire an ajax request.  In the controller I would get the data and return the partial view, then load that partial onto the page via jQuery.  This is a fairly standard thing.

Comment: @nurdyguy Could you show an example of how you would do this? Currently I just use a jQuery `.load()` function. It would be nice to find out how exactly to utilize ajax requests.